# how to create new json object using compose connector in logic app without change in order?

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

In my logic app, I have used the  `compose connector`.
After saving it, the output is in `asc order`

How can I maintain the order I specified in the compose connector?

The original json is -

```
{
"mainId":"2323",
"address":"DC"
}
```

But after saving, the order is:

```
{
"address":"DC",
"mainId":"2323"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you just compose the data, it will show asc order cause JavaScript JSON libraries default to alphabetical ordering of properties. So this is an expected behaviour that shouldn't have side effects if you stick to the JSON format. In other scenarios, like converting to XML.

If you insist on the custom order you could try with my. I create the json format string then compose it or parse it to json.

[image]

[image]

You could try [compose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#compose-action) or [parse json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-perform-data-operations#parse-json-action) action, they all could work. Hope this could help you.

Comment: great answer! thanks so much for all of your valueable input on stackoverflow, i learn a lot from reading your answers!