# How to change the order of the compose connector in logic apps(azure). By default it is asc order

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I get the data in a json format, in which i have table details (it has n number of rows and columns ). I want to send a mail and include the row details in the mail body. Right now i am able to send the mail and include the row details. I am using a compose connector to define the required rows. But the output is always in ascending order.(I want to display Message column first and then the Count column, but i always get Count column first and then Message column)  I want to customize the output.

I tried using initialize connector but since i am using the for-each loop i can not use Initialize connector. (Initialize connector have to be initialized at top.

[Before triggering the logic app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76S6k.png)

[image]

[After triggering the logic app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iuPk9.png)

[image]

[Current output i am getting:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVONz.png)

[image]

I want to customize the output i.e Message column first and then the count column

Answer (score 0):

This is an expected behaviour that shouldn't have side effects if you stick to the JSON format. It's because JavaScript JSON libraries default to alphabetical ordering of properties.

However if you insist on custom order, you could refer to my answer before [create new json object using compose connector](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56945966/10383250). You need create a string with the input you want the compose it or parse it to json.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the solution but I am not able to send the output of this string to Create HTML table connector, as Create HTML table connector takes array as input if i don't want to define any columns explicitly. And I don't want to mention column names explicitly so could you please suggest me if there is any solution?